# Have Patrick Jane and Kim Fischer slept together while on the island?

Tags: the-mentalist

In season 6, Patrick goes to an island off Venezuala after killing Red John, where he "accidentally" meets an American woman, Kim.

While on the island, the sexual tension between Patrick Jane and Kim Fischer is obvious, and they even [go on a date](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQsUk5_9boA).

However, it wasn't clear if they had the chance to sleep together (i.e. have sexual relationship) before leaving the island.

Is this mentioned or explained somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't mention any of that kind of relationship between them. I guess Patrick somehow knew in some level that she is onto something fishy and he just played along with his own style

Comment: @Vishwa thanks, though I was pretty sure Patrick really didn't know Kim's real intentions.

Comment: Could be, but I really wondered about that and he ain't the type of guy that somebody can make a fool of. Kim is definitely not a master manipulator. So I've watched those parts few times and I think in some level, he knew something is fishy about her. But he did followed her into US, I think thats because she gave him the kicks that he needed to go back, in deep, he really liked lisbon and he enjoyed their work,
of course this is my opinion, could be bullcrap, could be good, :)

Comment: @Vishwa hehe, well, without official source we're all just guessing here. I also think Patrick wanted to go back (mainly because of Lisbon, also because he was just bored there on the island) and just waited for a chance. Still, the part where he dates Kim and look at her with interest appeared real and authentic.